# Equivariant map, bijection of orbits of stabilizer and group

Tags: group-theory

I came a cross the following result:

Let $G$ be a finite group, let $\phi: M\to N$ be a G-equivariant map of $G$-sets $M$ and $N$ and let $n\in N$. Then there is a bijection of the set of orbits
$\Psi: \phi^{-1}(\{n\}) \big / Stab_G(n) \leftrightarrow \phi^{-1}(Gn) \big/ G$, where $Gn$ means the orbit of $n$ under $G$.

Can anyone tell me how the map $\Psi$ looks explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $\phi^{-1}(n)\subseteq \phi^{-1}(Gn)$ (because $n\in Gn$). Let us denote this inclusion by $f$. Then we define :

$$\bar{f}:\phi^{-1}(n)\rightarrow \phi^{-1}(Gn)/G $$

$$m\mapsto G.f(m)=G.m $$

My claim : $\bar{f}(m)=\bar{f}(m')$ if and only if $\exists g\in Stab_G(n)$ such that $g.m=m'$.

Assume that $g.m=m'$ with $g\in Stab_G(n)$ then $G.m'=G.g_0m=G.m$, hence $\bar{f}(m)=\bar{f}(m')$.

Assume that $\bar{f}(m)=\bar{f}(m')$ then $G.m=G.m'$, hence there exists $g\in G$ such that $m'=g.m$. We now apply $\phi$ on both sides (recall that $m$ and $m'$ are in $\phi^{-1}(n)$) so $\phi(m')=\phi(g.m)=g.\phi(m)$ hence $n=g.n$ so $g\in Stab_G(n)$ and we have the reverse implication.

From what I have shown we can quotient $\bar{f}$ to get an injection $\Psi$ :

$$\Psi:\phi^{-1}(n)/Stab_G(n)\rightarrow  \phi^{-1}(Gn)/G $$

$$Stab_G(n).m\mapsto \bar{f}(m)=G.m$$

Now to show that $\Psi$ is also surjective, it suffices to show that $\bar{f}$ is surjective which is an easy task I leave to you.

Comment: Thanks! I've got one follow up question concerning an application of this theorem. Suppose $B<A<G, U<G$, $t$ a representative of a coset $B\setminus A$ and $g \in G$. I would like to proove that there is a bijection between $Stab_U(Btg)$ and $\{Bx| BxU = BtgU, Ax=Aa\}$.
Set $\phi: M:=B\setminus G \to N:=A\setminus G$ which ist $G$-equivariant and $n:=Ag$. Then $\phi^{-1}(Ag)= \bigcup_{t \in T} \{Btg \}$ where T is a set of representatives for $B \setminus A $. Is that correct? If so I can not use the theorem above to prove the desired bijection, can I?

Comment: @DominikB., the action according to which you define $Stab_U(Btg)$ is this action of $U$ on $B/G$ : $u.Bh:=Bhu^{-1}$? furthermore what is the $a$ in the set (in the formula $Ax=Aa$)?  Finally you want to apply the theorem with the group $U$ acting ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the action you described. I'm sorry, the $a$ is supposed to be a $g$. And yes, I want to use the theorem with the group $U$ acting.

Comment: Let us say that $U$ is the trivial group then clearly $Stab_U(Btg)$ has only one element, on the other hand $\{Bx|Bx=Btg,Ax=Ag\}$ has no reason to have only one element, am I wrong?

Comment: I think you're right. But that is very surprising as the bijection I want to prove occurs in a paper ( it is proven differently there ) and is used in an algorithm. So it would actually surprise me if the result was wrong.. The paper is by Schmalz and is about an algorithm which is still used ( in GAP ) to compute double cosets.

Comment: May the bijection hold under the addition assumption that $U\neq \{1\}$?